# Подставить строку из подмассивов в цикле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
var Arr = [["а", "б", "в"], ["г", "д", "е", "ж"], ["з", "и"], ["к", "л", "м"]];
var ArrLen = Arr.length;

for(var i = 0; ArrLen > i; i++){
var textRes = "Строка "+Arr[i]+" cтрока "+Arr[i]+" cтрока "+Arr[i]+" cтрока "+Arr[i];
}

textRes
```

Получается такой ответ:

```
Строка к,л,м cтрока к,л,м cтрока к,л,м cтрока к,л,м
```

Как переделать код так чтобы получился ответ:

```
Строка а,б,в cтрока г,д,е,ж cтрока з,и cтрока к,л,м
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [["а", "б", "в"], ["г", "д", "е", "ж"], ["з", "и"], ["к", "л", "м"]];

let res = "Строка " + arr.join(' строка ');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Объявив переменную внутри цикла вы перезаписываете ее 4 раза.

Достичь желаемого результат можно следующими примерами:

**Пример 1. Без цикла, согласно логике вашего кода:**

```js
var Arr = [["а", "б", "в"], ["г", "д", "е", "ж"], ["з", "и"], ["к", "л", "м"]];

// Собираем требуемую строку вручную, как в вашем цикле
var textRes = "Cтрока " + Arr[0] 
  + " cтрока " + Arr[1] 
  + " cтрока " + Arr[2] 
  + " cтрока " + Arr[3];
    
console.log(textRes);
```

**Пример 2. С циклом, согласно логике вашего кода**

```js
let Arr = [["а", "б", "в"], ["г", "д", "е", "ж"], ["з", "и"], ["к", "л", "м"]];
// Массив со строками
let textResArr = [];

for (let i = 0, j = Arr.length; i < j; i++) {
  // Добавление строки в массив
  textResArr.push('строка ' + Arr[i]);
}

// Объединение элементов массива в строку
let textRes = textResArr.join(' ');

// Делаем первую букву заглавной
textRes = textRes[0].toUpperCase() + textRes.substring(1);

console.log(textRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо как советуют, через доступ к элемнтам поочередно. Либо на каждый подмассив запускать еще по циклу.